# Problems with chromedriver in headless mode

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, headless

I would like to know if anyone there has ever had a problem using the chromedriver in "headless" mode. In my case, when running selenium tests in this mode, the execution of the same is stopped indefinitely, not completing the test, nor does it give the relevant exception. Anyway, I would like to know if anyone can have any idea of what may be occurring. Thank you all.

```
public static void imprimirComprovanteEnvio(WebDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait, WebElement webElement)
        throws Exception {
    clicaByJE(By.xpath("//*[@id='formDetalhesDaResenha:comprovante']/span[2]"), driver, wait, webElement);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[text()='IMPRIMIR COMPROVANTE']")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='IMPRIMIR COMPROVANTE']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    Collection<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for (String handle : handles) {
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
        try {
            if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='plugin']")).isDisplayed()) {
                driver.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            continue;
        }
    }
    handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for (String handle : handles) {
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
    }
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='modalDoComprovante']/div[1]/a/span")).click();
    Thread.sleep(500);
}
```

Comment: Your code trials and error stack trace please.

Comment: no exception thrown on console. :(

Comment: Hi..Were you able to find a solution for your problem?

Comment: Not yet. I had to remove this part of the test code

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I also have problems with `driver.getWindowHandles();` when I am in headless mode, but sometimes (not always) I get an exception:  `org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`. You could check that first I think.